# Applovin AdclickListener not working in android

Tags: android, ads, applovin

I am integrating **AppLovin sdk** to integrate ads in my app.My app is a game app and I want my user to reward coins when they click on the ads.But adclicklistener of AppLovin seems not working in my case.

**The Code:**

```
 private AppLovinAdView adView;
    // Create AppLovin Ad View
                    final AppLovinSdk sdk = AppLovinSdk.getInstance(SceneActivity.this);
                    adView = new AppLovinAdView(sdk, AppLovinAdSize.INTERSTITIAL, SceneActivity.this);

                    //Show ad after 4 levels
                    if (currentLevel % 4 == 0) {
                            // An ad is available to display.  It's safe to call show.
                            AppLovinInterstitialAd.show(SceneActivity.this);
                            adView.loadNextAd();

                    }


                    adView.setAdClickListener(new AppLovinAdClickListener() {
                        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
                        @Override
                        public void adClicked(AppLovinAd arg0)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Adclicked");
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                            String today = sdf.format(new Date());
                            if (!today.equalsIgnoreCase(getLastDownloadDate())) {
                                // give coins once per day
                                modifyMoney(MONEY_DOWNLOAD_GAME);

                                // put last Download date
                                setLastDownloadDate(today);
                            }
                        }
                        });
```

The INTERSTITIAL ad is displaying but the click listener is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing `AppLovinInterstitialAd` (which internally owns its own instance of `AppLovinAdView`) and your own standalone `AppLovinAdView`. When you call `AppLovinInterstitialAd.show()`, you're bypassing your ad view which had the listener attached to it.

So you don't need to use `AppLovinAdView` at all... give this a try:

```
private void showInterstitial() {

    final AppLovinSdk sdk = AppLovinSdk.getInstance(mActivity);
    final AppLovinInterstitialAdDialog adDialog = AppLovinInterstitialAd.create(sdk, mActivity);

    adDialog.setAdClickListener(new AppLovinAdClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void adClicked(AppLovinAd appLovinAd) {
            // Ad clicked, add your on-click logic here
        }
    });

    adDialog.show(); // Display a pre-cached interstitial
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working.But there is an issue.The next ad is not showing...only one ad is coming repeatedly...previously there are numbers of interstitial were loading...but now inly one interstitial is coming repeatedly.I suspect adView.loadNextAd(); is not working.

Comment: Hi, again, your adView variable doesn't affect the interstitials; you should just remove it from your code. You can show another ad by just calling .show() on the `adDialog` variable again.